# Error with urlencode in python

Tags: python, encoding, urlencode

I have this:

```
a = {'album': u'Metamorphine', 'group': 'monoku', 'name': u'Son Of Venus (Danny\xb4s Song)', 'artist': u'Leandra', 'checksum': '2836e33d42baf947e8c8adef48921f2f76fcb37eea9c50b0b59d7651', 'track_number': 8, 'year': '2008', 'genre': 'Darkwave', 'path': u'/media/data/musik/Leandra/2008. Metamorphine/08. Son Of Venus (Danny\xb4s Song).mp3', 'user_email': 'diegueus9@gmail.com', 'size': 6624104}
data = urllib.urlencode(mp3_data)
```

And that raise an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "playkud.py", line 44, in <module>
    main()
  File "playkud.py", line 29, in main
    craw(args, options.user_email, options.group)
  File "/home/diegueus9/workspace/playku/src/client/playkud/crawler/crawler.py", line 76, in craw
    index(root, file, data, user_email, group)
  File "/home/diegueus9/workspace/playku/src/client/playkud/crawler/crawler.py", line 58, in index
    done = add_song(data[mp3file])
  File "/home/diegueus9/workspace/playku/src/client/playkud/service.py", line 32, in add_song
    return make_request(URL+'add_song/', data)
  File "/home/diegueus9/workspace/playku/src/client/playkud/service.py", line 14, in make_request
    data = urllib.urlencode(dict([k.encode('utf-8'),v] for k,v in mp3_data.items()))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/urllib.py", line 1250, in urlencode
    v = quote_plus(str(v))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xb4' in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)
```

and with ipython (2.5):

```
In [7]: urllib.urlencode(a)
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/diegueus9/<ipython console> in <module>()

/usr/lib/python2.5/urllib.pyc in urlencode(query, doseq)
   1248         for k, v in query:
   1249             k = quote_plus(str(k))
-> 1250             v = quote_plus(str(v))
   1251             l.append(k + '=' + v)
   1252     else:

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xb4' in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How i can fix it?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The `urlencode` library expects data in `str` format, and doesn't deal well with Unicode data since it doesn't provide a way to specify an encoding.  Try this instead:

```
mp3_data = {'album': u'Metamorphine',
     'group': 'monoku',
     'name': u'Son Of Venus (Danny\xb4s Song)',
     'artist': u'Leandra',
     'checksum': '2836e33d42baf947e8c8adef48921f2f76fcb37eea9c50b0b59d7651',
     'track_number': 8,
     'year': '2008', 'genre': 'Darkwave',
     'path': u'/media/data/musik/Leandra/2008. Metamorphine/08. Son Of Venus (Danny\xb4s Song).mp3',
     'user_email': 'diegueus9@gmail.com',
     'size': 6624104}

str_mp3_data = {}
for k, v in mp3_data.iteritems():
    str_mp3_data[k] = unicode(v).encode('utf-8')
data = urllib.urlencode(str_mp3_data)
```

What I did was ensure that all data is encoded into `str` using UTF-8 before passing the dictionary into the `urlencode` function.

Comment: Used this for the error message - unicodeencodeerror 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xb4'.  Thanks

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Django, take a look at Django's QueryDict class, it has a urlencode() method.

Or, for the helper function itself you may use [`urlencode`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.http.urlencode). It basically does what is described in the other answers as a wrapper around the original urllib.encode.

Comment: Although I didnt notice op is using django, I was, and found this answer very useful! Let me suggest an edit to elaborate

Comment: ok, I came here while searching for django error. That wrapper works. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that some of the values in your mp3_data dict are unicode strings that can't be represented in the default encoding used by `urlencode()` (while others are ASCII and still others are integers).  You can fix this by encoding those values before passing them to `urlencode()`.  On line 14 of /home/diegueus9/workspace/playku/src/client/playkud/service.py, in `make_request()`, try changing this:

```
data = urllib.urlencode(dict([k.encode('utf-8'),v] for k,v in mp3_data.items()))
```

to this:

```
data = urllib.urlencode(dict([k.encode('utf-8'),unicode(v).encode('utf-8')] for k,v in mp3_data.items()))
```

Comment: They don't have to be strings for this to work.  Note my use of the unicode() call to convert any integers or plain strings to unicode before encoding as utf-8.  If it really doesn't work, I'd be interested in seeing what the failure looks like  (Are you sure you replied to the right answer?)

Answer (score 3):

the problem is, that you want to cast a unicode-string to a string, but there are some characters that have to be converted to ASCII first. So I would advice you to search for strings that are not ASCII and then encode them as follows:

try to change **for example** where **v** is a unicode-string to:

```
quote_plus(str(v))
```

to

```
quote_plus(str(v.encode("utf-8")))
```

that should help

---

If you do not have to use Python 2.x, you could switch to Python 3.x, where all strings are unicode by default. But you have to convert some things for it (you could automate this party or full with [2to3](http://docs.python.org/library/2to3.html)).

Comment: I think that, but is a little nasty because is in the core of python :/

Comment: hmm.. I don't think it's the urllib's fault. maybie there's anywhere a string, that's not encoded to ASCII. Can you search for that, or provide more code?

Comment: if you see the traceback you can read the exception is raised in /usr/lib/python2.5/urllib.pyc

Comment: by the way, i can't use python 3 :(